# Does executable file created using pyinstaller require Python and other modules installed on PC?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I created an executable file(.exe) using pyinstaller.
If I have to share it, does the other computer require Python and other modules installed?

Comment: If you include all the required modules in the generated executable, then no.

Comment: Depends on the flags that you passed when you ran pyinstaller, if you ran the -F flag then there's no need of sending more files than the .exe file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pyinstaller` just compress all the libraries and the code into one executable file, so no. But If you want other to run your Python file, they do need the libraries you used in your code. You can use some arguments with `Pyinstaller` to make it one executable file.

```
pyinstaller -F <my_file> # -F == one file
```

For More information about `Pyinstaller` and his features, you can read the manual [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) or just use the help argument with `Pyinstaller`

```
pyinstaller -h
```